# Create a formula where the operator and operands are specified in cells in a different sheet and also an operand is defined in the current sheet

Tags: vba, excel-formula

I have a formula in cell (in the green box below) referencing a cell in the current sheet (C42) [not shown] and other cells [B134 and D134] in another sheet.

[image]

The cells formula:

=IF(AND(C42>'Common For All'!B134,(C42<'Common For All'!D134)),'Common For All'!H134,0)

I just want to build the same formula above using the references to the comparison operators in cols A and C (in the other sheet) instead of hardcoding the comparison operators as they may change. And I would then just change the tables comparison operators and hence the cell will perform dynamically.

The other sheet:

[image]

Just not sure how to string them into the formula.

I tried:

=IF(AND(C42&" "&TEXTJOIN(" ",TRUE,'Common For All'!A134:'Common For All'!B134),(C42&" "&TEXTJOIN(" ",TRUE,'Common For All'!C134:'Common For All'!D134))),'Common For All'!H134,0)

It looks like it resolves it, but then fails.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, making a text string look like a logical expression  does not actually create a logical expression, it remains just a string of text characters. This is why the first argument of the `=IF()` function in the OP evaluates as a `#VALUE!` error.

There are functions,such as `VALUE` and `INDIRECT`, which can be used to convert text strings. `VALUE` converts a string of characters which looks like a number to the number itself, so `VALUE("10")` delivers the numeric value of `10`. Similarly, `INDIRECT` converts a string of characters which looks like a cell reference to the cell reference. `INDIRECT("A1")` is the same as writing the cell reference `A1`.

Unfortunately, there is no worksheet function which provides the ability convert a text string which looks like a formula (or part of formula) to the formula itself, so there is nothing provided that can directly convert a text string such as
`"152161.41418118 > 123000"`
into the logical comparison of
`152161.41418118>123000`.

If the possible operators are known in advance, then there are ways of allowing a chosen operator to be specified in a worksheet cell in the way sought in the OP.

One such way is to list the possible operators and then match the chosen operator against that list using the `MATCH` function. The results of this can then be used as the first argument of a `CHOOSE` function where the subsequent arguments represent the actual formula possibilities. This is illustrated below.

[image: Specifying different operators as entries on the worksheet]

The formula in cell `F2` can be copied downwards into cells `F3`, `F4`, etc.

This method is not foolproof. In particular, the `MATCH` function will treat the `*` character as a wildcard and cause it to evaluate the first formula (second argument) of the `CHOOSE` function. In addition, specifying an operator not included in the list of operators will result in a `#N/A` error.

### The real problem?

Given the numerical ranges specified I am not convinced that the approach of varying operators is helpful or appropriate. The data showing in worksheet 'Common For All' appears to be based on a series of 6 contiguous numerical ranges.

First, I have used the phrase "appears to be" above rather than "is" because there is an overlap in these numerical ranges. For example, the first numerical range is $0 to $97,001 whilst the second is $97,000 to $123,001. For a value such as $97,000.50 there is a question about which of these two numerical ranges does it fall into and, more importantly, what is the yearly adjustment value (from column `H`) that is appropriate to such a value. Is it $0.00 (from the lower of the two numerical ranges) or $937.20 (from the upper numerical range)?

Second, I am assuming that in the 'current sheet' the 6 rows from row 84 to 89 are intended to correspond to the 6 numerical ranges defined in worksheet 'Common For All'. The OP identifies that cell `E86` is intended to test whether `C42` falls within the third numerical range of worksheet 'Common For All' and, if it does, to deliver the corresponding column `H` value and 0 otherwise. I am assuming that cells `E84`, `E85`, `E87`, `E88` and `E89` similarly act on the first, second, fourth, fifth and sixth numerical ranges and, further, the real problem is to identify which of the 6 numerical ranges contains `C42` and then to determine the column `H` value corresponding to this numerical range.

So, if my second set of assumptions is correct and the intention is to utilise contiguous (and therefore **non-overlapping**) numerical ranges then (i) these can be defined by their lower limits and (ii) the appropriate value from column `H` can be obtained using the `VLOOKUP` function.

In fact, the 6 values in column `B` define 6 such numerical ranges and a formula such as:

`=VLOOKUP(C42,'Common For All'!$B$132:$H$136,7,TRUE)`

will deliver the value from column `H` that applies to the range in which `C42` falls.

When `VLOOKUP` is used in this way there is an important proviso that the values in `Common For All!$B132:$B136` must be in ascending order. The worksheet snippet in the OP shows that this is currently the case.

I strongly suspect that the flexibility being sought in the OP can be achieved simply by adjusting the lower boundaries of the numerical ranges and, perhaps, by adjusting the number of numerical ranges. Simply changing the values in `Common For All!$B132:$B136` achieves the first of these (and dispenses with the need for columns A, C and D which become redundant). Using a named range for `Common For All!$B132:$H136` and adjusting its definition if the number of numerical ranges changes copes with the second type of adjustment.

Comment: I resolved the 'here is an overlap in these numerical ranges' issue. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Rather than putting your solution as a comment you should add it as an answer. You should also tag your original post with "VBA" because that is what you have considered as a possible solution.

Comment: Ok. I made the suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

As a solution, I created a function to use that evaluates the data in my table based upon what I send it. It returns TRUE or FALSE.

So in a cell, I added:

=IF(AND(EvaluateYearlyPenaltyExpression(C42,'Common For All'!A132,'Common For
All'!B132),GetYearlyPenaltyExpression(C42,'Common For All'!C132,'Common For
All'!D132)),'Common For All'!H132,0)

```
Function EvaluateYearlyPenaltyExpression(income As Currency, comparisonoperator 
As String, threshold As Currency) As Variant

  Dim compareop

  compareop = UCase(Trim(comparisonoperator))

  idx = InStr("AND,OR,XOR", compareop)

  If idx > 0 Then
    ' Build expression using Excel logical function (AND(), OR(), XOR()).
    expr = compareop & "(" & income & "," & threshold & ")"
  Else
    ' Build and expression like "x + y", "x < y", ...
    expr = income & compareop & threshold
  End If

  EvaluateYearlyPenaltyExpression = Evaluate(expr)
End Function
```